# How do I get the PHP-FPM process to terminate when a user aborts request? (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, request, abort, php

I know Nginx has nothing to do with the PHP-FPM process, but I would much prefer if the PHP-FPM process died if a user aborts so it doesn't continue doing needless things or wasting resources. For PHP-FPM/Nginx the `trigger_error` will happen regardless of user abort:

```
<?php

sleep(30);
trigger_error('Still happened?');

?>
```

How can I do user aborts for PHP-FPM? (if possible)

Answer (score 3):

This is not implemented by php-fpm, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251224/nginx-php-stop-process-at-canceled-request).

Setting `ignore_user_abort(FALSE)` only works when PHP sends data over the socket, not when it is busy calculating a response.

Ideally, it should be implemented in php-fpm, but I don't think it will be very easy, given that PHP is mostly single threaded.

In emergency situations, you could kill all php-fpm processes with a broken connection. Assuming you have php-fpm listening on localhost:9000, this would work:

```
netstat -ntp | grep 127.0.0.1:9000 | grep php-fpm | grep CLOSE_WAIT |\
awk ' { print $7; } ' | cut -d/ -f1 | while read pid; do
    echo "Killing php-fpm/$pid because client has closed connection"
    kill $pid
done
```

Answer (score 2):

> You have to check your `nginx` config, before trying to set the behaviour on the PHP script.

The settings linked by [@YAAK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12920528/3088045) don't *always* work with `nginx`. In my actual case it is not possible to stop the script, regardless what you do on PHP side.

Playing on the *nginx fastcgi* parameter `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort` (default set to `off`) could help.

Additionally, a manual solution (just for *development* environment) is to execute (on *Linux*): `sudo service php-fpm restart`, so that the worker process running the script will be killed (**beware:** this will kill *all* the workers or other running services).

Answer (score 1):

> You can decide whether or not you want a client disconnect to cause
>   your script to be aborted.

According to PHP Manual : [Connection Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)

To set this behavior use [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

[`ignore_user_abort(FALSE);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) will abort running of PHP script after client disconnect.

[`ignore_user_abort(TRUE);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) will ignore the client disconnect and continues to run the script.

In the second case, you may also want to use [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) based on your needs to give your script enough time to accomplish the task.

This setting has been tested in a `PHP-FPM/nginx` environment successfully.